# Couchbase Ruby client connection refused using node_list

Tags: ruby, couchbase

I have set up couchbase on 2 servers(192.168.56.4 & 192.168.56.5) both in the same bucket(default).
I'm able to connect to each individually, but not when passing the node_list arg as shown below:

It connnects when I do so:

```
client = Couchbase.connect("http://192.168.56.4:8091/pools/default")
```

OR

```
client = Couchbase.connect("http://192.168.56.5:8091/pools/default")
```

but I get a refuse connection error when I try:

`c = Couchbase.connect( :pool => "default", :port => 8091, :node_list => ['http://192.168.56.4', 'http://192.168.56.5'])`

OR

`c = Couchbase.connect( :pool => "default", :port => 8091, :node_list => ['192.168.56.4', '192.168.56.5'])`

OR

`c = Couchbase.connect( :pool => "default", :node_list => ['http://192.168.56.4:8091', 'http://192.168.56.5:8091'])`

AND with other combinations that I have tried...

So, any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

BTW, just in case anyone asks, they seem to be working properly when it comes to replicate the data between themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Well seems like it's not implemented in gem 1.1.x branch, according to developer team. So it's needed to install the 1.2.x version (review version, by the time I'm writing this) or you can go and implement it yourself.

It would not be that hard, since you just need to implement a method that loop thru a node list, trying to connect to the first server available.